# Post request works on my local computer, but doesn't work on remote server

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

On my computer, I have nodejs 10.13.0 and on my server I run ubuntu v10.22.1. I use express js for the server.
I have many endpoints (PUT,POST,GET) on both. So I develop it on my windows computer and I push to the Linux server. All the endpoints work as expected on both machines, but for some reason, this endpoint doesn't work on the ubuntu server. It returns 403. The exact same code works well on windows. Have you ever faced such? I use postman in both cases.

```
router.post('/refresh-token', (req, res, next) => {
let refreshToken = req.cookies.jwt_refresh
let authorization = req.headers.authorization_refresh

try {
    if (refreshToken) {
        req.user = jwt.verify(refreshToken, config.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    } else if (authorization) {
        req.user = jwt.verify(authorization, config.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    } else {
        res.status(403);
        res.send()
    }
} catch (error) {
    res.status(403);
    res.send({error: error.message, success: false})
}

Tokens.findOne({
    where: {user_id: req.user.id, client_id: req.user.client}
}).then(token => {
    if (token) {
        let refreshToken = token.refresh_token
        try {
            jwt.verify(refreshToken, config.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET)

            let newToken = generateAccessToken(req.user.username, token.user_id, req.user.client)
            let newRefreshToken = generateRefreshToken(req.user.username, token.user_id, req.user.client)

            res.cookie("jwt", newToken, {secure: true, httpOnly: true})
            res.cookie("jwt_refresh", newRefreshToken, {secure: true, httpOnly: true})
            res.send({
                success: true,
                error: null,
                result: {
                    access_token: newToken, refresh_token: newRefreshToken
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("refresh token error", error)
            res.status(403);
            res.send({error: {message: "refresh token error, please log in"}, success: false})
        }
    }
}).catch(error => handleError(error, {}, res, next, statusCode = 403))
```

})

Comment: Hi @TheLetch, could you please check if you are using the necessary cookies, when you are sending the requests.

Comment: @KarthikRadhakrishnan I should only send the cookie if it is from the browser. How could it explain the fact that the same request behaves differently on different platforms?

Comment: Look in the network tab and see what the differences are between the headers when running locally and on remote server. If there are differences, it may be worth editing the answer to include these

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? I'm facing the same thing here

Comment: @El.MENSI I had to downgrade my node version for it to work